# How Realize a Artisan/cron operation with sub minute frequency?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduling, frequency

Hello I know that the Artisan scheduler is invoked by cron , and the minimum frequncy in a crontab is "everyminute"

How can I obtain a higher frequency?
I may implement it via software(PHP): like the script is invoked every minute but the script itself will timer other sub-operations?
Or better I can realize it via bash script (maybe always invoked via cron... but will manage inside multiple calls per minute, with processes watching/garbage collection)

I bet there's already something that implement a server side routine with frequency higher than 60".
Do you know any real working example/implementation that will realize the point of my question?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask about the real problem you're facing instead of what you wrote here? Without code or substantial problem, we can just throw opinions and guesses - that's not what you need to solve the real problem.

Comment: Yes true, maybe the question leaves too much to interpretation... I dont think I actually need an opinion but an experience of a working example, without performance flaws...

Comment: I like the idea of implementing a daemon, how would you do that? (in a PHP/laravel flavour :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the operations are not intensive and they would *not* take any real amount to time, otherwise your cron jobs will overlap and you'll hate yourself

```
$times_per_minute = 10;
for($i=0; $i<$times_per_minute; $i++) {
    do_my_awesome_function();
    sleep(60/$times_per_minute);
}
```

Then schedule your cron job is to run the above code every minute.

[EDIT]

A fancier version checks for run-time occlusion:

```
 $start_time = time(); 
 $times_per_minute = 10;
 for($i=0; $i<$times_per_minute; $i++) {
        do_my_awesome_function();
        $actual_runtime = time() - $start_time;
        $predicted_runtime = $i * (60/$times_per_minute);
        $offset_time = $predicted_runtime - $actual_runtime;
        sleep((60 - $offset_time)/$times_per_minute);
 }
```

An even fancier version could test to see if there's enough time to run the loop again:

```
 $start_time = time(); 
 $times_per_minute = 10;
 for($i=0; $i<$times_per_minute; $i++) {
        if($i > 0) {
            $average_run_time = (time() - $start_time) / $i
            if(time() - $start_time + $average_run_time > 60) {
                break;
            }
        }
        do_my_awesome_function();
        $actual_runtime = time() - $start_time;
        $predicted_runtime = $i * (60/$times_per_minute);
        $offset_time = $predicted_runtime - $actual_runtime;
        sleep((60 - $offset_time)/$times_per_minute);
 }
```

Comment: Yes this is the basic solution I had in mind when I was saying " I may implement it via software(PHP)", but I'm sure It might get weird, awesomeness is not guaranteed to be so fast...always :)

Comment: Yeah, If you need something running more than 20-30 times per minute you'll need something other than PHP or cron. Something event driven like NodeJS or Java would handle this far better. I've added some checks you can include that can *reduce* the likelihood of collisions.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Thanks